# Java Docker Api вызвать команду и получить ответ из одного контейнера в другом

Tags: java, api, docker, exec

Есть два контейнера id 111111111111 и id 222222222222

Мне нужно посредствам Java выполнить команду из первого контейнера на втором. Я настроил сети прокинул сокет все отрабатывает когда я запускаю как бы через CLI:

```
docker exec 222222222222 sh -c 'cd /etc/ && ls'
```

получаю в консоли вывод корректный:

```
/etc/java # docker exec 222222222222 sh -c 'cd /etc/ && ls'
alpine-release
apk
conf.d
crontabs
ethertypes
fstab
group
group-
hostname
hosts
```

Но мне нужно, чтобы это делалось по средствам Java.
Я подключил зависимость последней версии:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.github.docker-java</groupId>
  <artifactId>docker-java</artifactId>
  <version>3.3.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Я корректно сконфигурировал и настроил DockerClient, потому что простые команды у меня отрабатывают например вот эта действительно выдает мне список всех живых контейнеров:

```
    List<Container> containers = dockerClient.listContainersCmd().exec();
```

Мне нужно чтобы я мог запустить именно команду на другом контейнере, а так же получить вывод этой команды, если таковой имеется. Для иллюстрации приведу код, который успешно компилируется и отрабатывает:

```
public String execCommand(String containerId, String command) {
    log.debug("Running command: " +command+ "in container: "+containerId);
    String execId = dockerClient.execCreateCmd(containerId).withCmd(command).withAttachStdout(true).withAttachStderr(true).exec().getId();
    final StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
    dockerClient.execStartCmd(execId).exec(new ResultCallback.Adapter<Frame>() {
        @Override
        public void onNext(Frame object) {
            output.append(new String(object.getPayload(), UTF_8));
            super.onNext(object);
        }
    });
    log.debug("Result of command: " +command+ " in container: "+containerId+" OUTPUT: "+output);
    return output.toString();
}
```

однако, при всех попытках переменная output постоянно пустая я не понимаю почему.
я передаю точно такую же команду "cd /etc/ && ls" хотя я пытался не только с ней.
что делать и как быть?
какая лучшая практика для того, чтобы выполнить команду по средствам java docker api и получить результат в переменную string?

только не надо тут вставлять код от ChatGPT я уже боролся с ним, он тупо генерирует wikipedia  причем на depricated методах.